# Why private members are actually inherited by subclass

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance, ide, private

I know the Doc/Oracle indicates that subclass don't inherit private members from superclass.

But when debugging a program, we can definitely see "private members are inherited" if we trace the variables using ctrl F7 and Ctrl F4. That is quite strange.

Even if I override the default constructor with empty `{}`, it actually still inherit private members, though private members are not accessible.

Quite confusing between terminology and real work.

I created a sample, with three class:

```
public class Inheritance {        

public static void main(String[] args) {

    teacher t1 = new teacher();
    t1.setGrd(80);
    System.out.println(t1.getGrd());
}
}


public class person {
    private int age=90;
    public void person(){

    }
}

public class teacher extends person {
    private int grade;

    public void setGrd(int age){
        grade=age;
    }
    public int getGrd(){
        return grade;
    }
}
```

When tracing it:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code . Private members are not inherited by subclass

Comment: Inheritance is for *is-a* association. So, if a Fruit has a private field color, a banana also has, since it **is** a fruit. But it's not inherited in the sense that the subclass doesn't have access to this field: it can't read it or write it. It's only known by the base class.

Comment: Is [this the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) you mean? It does say "private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class." , but the immediate next paragraph is about how to access it in subclasses: "This means that they can only be directly accessed from the Bicycle class. We still need access to these values, however. This can be done indirectly by adding public methods that obtain the field values"

Comment: "*I know the Doc/Oracle indicates that subclass don't inherit private members from superclass.*" Show the exact source.

Comment: i posted the codes, and as well as a picture for tracing. please have a look at it.

Comment: You didn't post the link to the docs which you refer to.

Comment: If any of the answers here answered your question (As stated), please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon to its left.

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation means that the sub-class cannot see/access private members of the super-class. That doesn't mean they don't still exist in the super-class. The debugger is showing the full state of the instance, which includes the private state of the super-class.

Comment: actually the private members exists in the object of subclass. it is inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Not inheriting private members would definitely violate [*Liskov subistution principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so I think you got it the wrong way. Suppose a simple example:

```
public Foo {
  private int x = 50;
  public void yell() { System.out.println(x); }
}

public Bar extends Foo {

}

Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.yell();
```

What it is supposed to happen here if a `private` field is not inherited? You see that something is wrong in your deductions. `private` members are all inherited but can't be accessed.

This may sound useless but it is not since you could have a lot of functionality implemented in super type methods which rely on internal state which are not needed by inerithing classes.

Comment: my question is, Oracle declares private members will not be inherited.

Comment: They're inherited but not visible to the subclass, which is different.

Answer (score 1):

> But when debugging a program, we can definitely see "private members are inherited" if we trace the variables using ctrl F7 and Ctrl F4.

Not inherited - the IDE shows all<sup>1</sup> fields of the type hierarchy to help with debugging. It does so via reflection by something like traversing all superclasses ([`getSuperclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass())) and collecting all the fields ([`getDeclaredFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())). There are no language semantics in play here, it's a "hack".

I don't know what IDE you are using, but that "Inherited" label is not a precise choice of words, although it brings the point across well. You can file a ticket with the maintainers asking to use a more precise word.

<sup><sup>1</sup> IDEs can give you options to enable/disable what it shows, like constants (`static final`) or `static` fields, which are also not inherited.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply. I am thinking about one thing:
when we only instantiate a subclass to  'sub-obj', if the private member (prvt) is not inherited, why we can use the user-defined getprvt() to get the value or use setprvt() to modify the value. The private 'prvt' actually already exists in the memory.  and if we setter() the prvt first, then we can getter() to get the modified value, which means 'prvt' is kept for sub-obj instead of being a local variable to the two methods.  I am not quite familiar with memory management in Java, not quite sure about this.

Comment: @longe If you're asking about the memory model then post a different question. Your current question asks about the conflict between your IDE and the docs.